# Getting array key(protected)-value from an array inside object (response from RTM-php)?

Tags: php, arrays, object, protected

When using php library for RTM (https://github.com/bartosz-maciaszek/php-rtm), I am getting a response for a particular tasks-list like this:

```
Rtm\DataContainer Object
(
    [attributes:Rtm\DataContainer:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rtm\DataContainer Object
                (
                    [attributes:Rtm\DataContainer:private] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 19594773
                            [taskseries] => Rtm\DataContainer Object
                                (
                                    [attributes:Rtm\DataContainer:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 310899576
                                            [created] => 2013-10-03T05:35:52Z
                                            [modified] => 2013-11-06T17:24:36Z
                                            [name] => A new task
                                            [source] => js
                                            [url] => 
                                            [location_id] =>

                                        )
                                )
                        )
              )
      )
)
```

I want to get the value of `[name]`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could understand from the docs, you have to call something like

```
$receivedObject->getTaskSeries()->getName()
```

Or there is a suggestion to apply toArray or toJson to returned object - that should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but `getName()` gives fatal error: `Call to a member function getName() on a non-object`. toArray is probably right way to do it.

Comment: Ok. Got it fixed..traversing it using foreach did the trick for me. However for real response object I have to use foreach twice: `foreach ($response as $item) {
    $ts = $item->getTaskseries();
    foreach ($ts as $item2) {
        $name[] = $item2->getName();
    }
}
print_r($name[0]);`